# Recibir Array /Crearlo en Angular2

Tags: angular

Tengo que recibir un Array en Angular2, como aún no tengo hecho lo de "enviarlo" estoy simulando que lo estoy recibiendo, el problema está que cuando mediante un *ngFor recorra la longitud del array no hace nada.

```
 @Input() steps: Array<number>[4]; //Así no funciona

  //  steps: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3, 4]; //asi si

   Supuestamente tendría que sacar 4 veces 'ey'

   <div>
    <div class='line'></div>
    <clr-icon *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index" shape="circle" 
    [ngClass]="'circle' + (i + 1 )" size="36">
      ey
    </clr-icon>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es crear un array on x length?. Si ese es el caso puedes crear el array usando new Array(tamanho del array)

```
miArray = new Array(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentacion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) de TypeScript, la forma que intentas haciendo no es correcta (crear el array pasandole un tamaño), y la que tienes comentada es la que si funciona.

Los valores dentro de **`[]`** es cada uno de los elementos y no el tamaño del array.

```
let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

Quizás estas confundido con como se instancia un array en **C#**?

```
int[] array = new int[4];
```

Comment: Pero en let , tu le estás diciendo los *valores* al Array y por tanto tienes posiciones, yo no quiero tener valores, yo quiero tener la longitud, es declararlo con 'x' posiciones.